# Is it safe to eject a hard drive during encryption?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, encryption

I am currently encrypting my external hard drive (1TB), but the process takes a while. I'm always using it on the go with my laptop, so I have to eject it at some point. However, after I eject my hard drive, the light on my hard drive is still on, indicating it's still active. I ejected it properly, but it still flashes on. So I decide to just shut down my laptop and plug out my hard drive.

Is this safe to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is fine — if the disk has been ejected, it is no longer in use. I have done this myself during encryption of my Time Machine disk. Reconnecting the drive continues the encryption process from where it left off. Of course, make sure the disk is ejected before disconnecting it.